# how to pass jsonpayload in the CreateAppleTemplateRegistrationAsync notification hub method

Tags: apple-push-notifications, azure-notificationhub

I have created a hub client and I want to pass the custom template in the CreateAppleTemplateRegistrationAsync method. I want to pass the below template payload
{ alert: '$(message)', badge: '#(count)', sound: 'default' }

How to pass the above template as a string in the method.

Answer (score 0):

The template payload has to be a valid json string and abide by Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CreatingtheNotificationPayload.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH10-SW1).

This is an example of doing it with literal strings in C#.

```
var apnsTemplate = @"{
    ""aps"" : {
    ""alert"" : {
        ""title"" : ""$(title)"",
            ""subtitle"" : ""$(subtitle)"",
            ""body"" : ""$(message)""
        },
        ""category"" : ""GAME_INVITATION""
    },
    ""gameID"" : ""12345678""
}";
```

This snippet can be adapted for your desired payload and programming language of choice.